# Suppress a serie of Tags into a document

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgility but I am not really used to HTML documents.
A combination of tags create problem when printed, so I decided to cut them but how?

```
<p ><br clear=all> 
</span></p>
```

I have a HtmlDocument that I load at the beginning and then I try to cut the previous tags.

to cut them I have tried:

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document; // get the document
  foreach (var node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div"))
        {
            IEnumerable<HtmlNode> test= node.ChildNodes;
            foreach(HtmlNode val in test)
            {
                if (val.Name == "br") //Want to check if I go through the node, I am looking for
                {
                    int a = 0;
                    a++;
                    IEnumerable <HtmlAttribute> attribute = node.GetAttributes();
                    foreach(HtmlAttribute att in attribute)
                    {
                     if (att.Name == "clear")
                     {
                        HtmlNode getNode = node.NextSibling;
                        node.Remove();
                     }
                   }
                }
            }            

        }
```

It doesn't work!!!
If I would insert :

```
foreach (var node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br"))
```

I could remove the Tag  but I cannot access to the following node

could you help me?

Comment: what is the `nodes` in the code?

Comment: what is document in this code document.DocumentNode.Descendants().ToList();

Comment: Oh sorry, I have been such in my code, that it seemed to be normal. document is an HthmlDocument document.and the node is :  HtmlNode nodes. Both are Html-agility objects.